# Trying to create multiple unique short URLs

Tags: c#, servicestack

I want to make a post method that returns a list of shortened URLs when given a body containing multiple URLs in JSON.

This is my post method:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public object Post(CreateShortUrlRequest request) //Post an array/list of URLs to the database and get a respective list of short URL
    {
        using (Task4URLEntities db = new Task4URLEntities())
        {
            var urls = new List<string>();
            foreach (string LongUrl in request.LongUrl)
            {
                var item = new ShortURLs
                {
                    LongUrl = LongUrl,
                    ShortUrl = GetUrl(),
                    DateCreated = DateTime.Now
                };
                urls.Add($"http://localhost/{item.ShortUrl}");
                db.ShortURLs.Add(item);
            }

            var campaign = new Campaign
            {
                CampaignName = request.CampaignName,
                Enddate = request.Enddate,
                Startdate = request.Startdate
            };

            db.Campaign.Add(campaign);

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Response.WriteAsync("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }

            return new CreateShortUrlResponse
            {
                Response = urls,
                CampaignId = campaign.CampaignId
            };
        }
    }

    public string GetUrl()
    {
        var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        var stringChars = new char[5];
        var random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
        {
            stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
        }
        var finalString = new String(stringChars);
        return finalString;
    }

 }
```

My problem is that when I send my post request on Postman for a list of URLs in JSON, I will get unique URLs as response for the first post if i click send again then I will get a response in which every returned short URL is the same.

How can I rectify this?

Comment: Don't understand your question, When you submit a POST request to shorten URL's then you are getting list of unique URL's back and are these not the shortened urls ? Why do you need to send the same URL set as POST request again?

Comment: because i want a unique short url for every long url posted even if it has already been posted before. So that different users can obtain different urls for the same site

Comment: Sounds like your `Random` is getting seeded with the same value. When you say " every returned short URL is the same", do you mean they're the same as the last `POST` or they're new values compared to the last `POST`, but all exactly the same? Are you sending the `POST` requests in rapid succession? Is that actually how you're creating the `Random` instance, or are you passing it a seed? Does it make a difference if you make the `Random` instance a static field on the `MyServices` class and only create it one time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that when you say "every returned short URL is the same" you mean that the `CreateShortUrlResponse.Response` property contains the exact same URL `n` number of times, where `n` is the number of URLs that you requested. I'm also assuming, based on that behavior, that this is a .NET Framework project, and not a .NET Core project.

If that's the case, then the problem is that creating new instances of `Random` in such a tight loop is resulting in each one being created with the exact same seed value. When you create an instance of `Random` in the .NET Framework with the empty constructor, it uses `Environment.TickCount` as the seed. So, if you create two instances of `Random` in rapid succession, they will both have the same seed and therefore generate the same values.

The [documentation on `Random` speaks to this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8).

> On the .NET Framework, initializing two random number generators in a tight loop or in rapid succession creates two random number generators that can produce identical sequences of random numbers. In most cases, this is not the developer's intent and can lead to performance issues, because instantiating and initializing a random number generator is a relatively expensive process.
>
> Both to improve performance and to avoid inadvertently creating separate random number generators that generate identical numeric sequences, we recommend that you create one Random object to generate many random numbers over time, instead of creating new Random objects to generate one random number.
>
> However, the Random class isn't thread safe. If you call Random methods from multiple threads, follow the guidelines discussed in the next section.

So, you might make the `Random` instance a member of the `MyServices` class instead of creating a new instance every time you call `GetUrl`.

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public object Post(CreateShortUrlRequest request) //Post an array/list of URLs to the database and get a respective list of short URL
    {
        using (Task4URLEntities db = new Task4URLEntities())
        {
            var urls = new List<string>();
            foreach (string LongUrl in request.LongUrl)
            {
                var item = new ShortURLs
                {
                    LongUrl = LongUrl,
                    ShortUrl = GetUrl(),
                    DateCreated = DateTime.Now
                };
                urls.Add($"http://localhost/{item.ShortUrl}");
                db.ShortURLs.Add(item);
            }

            var campaign = new Campaign
            {
                CampaignName = request.CampaignName,
                Enddate = request.Enddate,
                Startdate = request.Startdate
            };

            db.Campaign.Add(campaign);

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Response.WriteAsync("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }

            return new CreateShortUrlResponse
            {
                Response = urls,
                CampaignId = campaign.CampaignId
            };
        }
    }

    public string GetUrl()
    {
        var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        var stringChars = new char[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
        {
            stringChars[i] = chars[_rng.Next(chars.Length)];
        }
        var finalString = new String(stringChars);
        return finalString;
    }
    private Random _rng = new Random();
 }
```